# Jquery mobile 1.4.0 remove disc from custom icon

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, icons

As a wrote in the subject I'm going crazy for remove the disc from the custom icon on my JQM APP.
I've tried some solution found on the web but nothing is working.

This is a demo where on the left I got my home custom icon with disc and on the right the native home icon without disc:

http://jsfiddle.net/5nBVa/

This is the code I use:

```
.ui-icon-myhome:after {
background-image: url("http://www.mywine.info/images/theme/home.png");
/* Make your icon fit */
background-size: 24px 24px;
background-color: transparent;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius:0px;
border-radius:0px;
}
```

Anyone can show me the way to remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you just need to set the `background-color` of the link to transparent:

```
.ui-icon-myhome{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5nBVa/3/)**

**UPDATE:** OP wants image to fill the circular button and be the same size as a standard icon button with disc.

The icon is actually on the anchor tag's :after. Making the `background-size`, the `width` and `height` the same size as the button will cause the image to take up the whole button space. Adjust the `margin-top` and `margin-left` to keep the image centered within the button:

```
.ui-icon-myhome:after {
    background-image: url("http://www.mywine.info/images/theme/home.png");
    /* Make your icon fit */
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    background-color: transparent;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    width: 32px  !important;
    height: 32px  !important;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
    margin-left: -15px !important;
}
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5nBVa/4/)**

Comment: Yes, but in this way the circle is only transparent and the image can't fill all the space and it's smaller that the right one. Do you think there's a way to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @EnricoPasqualotto, yes, see my updated answer. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5nBVa/4/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but have you tried adding `class="ui-nodisc-icon"` ?

Check **Removing the disc** in the following page : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/icons/index.html

Comment: yes I try both on the div container and on a element but nothing change.

Comment: Are you trying to try to use css to remove the circle around your icon that is actually in the png image?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to remove the circle around the native icon but not my custom PNG icon